# How to get value of placeholder attribute of ngcontrol in typescript .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting placeholder attribute as an undefined in typescript .ts file.
Here is my code which i wrote-

HTML Code-

```
<label class="lab1">Closing date</label>
<input placeholder="M/d/yyyy" type="text" [(ngModel)]="_module.ClosingDate" ngControl="ClosingDate" #ClosingDate="ngForm">
<button type="submit" class="custombutton" (click)="Test1(ClosingDate)">Get Placeholder value</button>
```

Typescript file code-

```
function Test1() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i].name); //here i got correct thing i.e.- "ClosingDate"
        alert(arguments[i].placeholder); //here i'm expecting - "M/d/yyyy" but i got wrong value - "undefined"
    }
}
```

When i click on my button it call method Test1() with argument "ClosingDate" which is name of my ngcontrol. I found that name of ngcontrol in Test1() method through arguments, but when i want the value of placeholder in alert window i get "undefined" in place of "M/d/yyyy".

The code i wrote in .ts file is running successfully with html input control, but when i use ngcontrol then it not running successfully, suggest me, how i get placeholder value.

Thanks
Kapil Bhagwat

Answer (score 2):

```
<label class="lab1">Closing date</label>
<input #myInput placeholder="M/d/yyyy" type="text" [(ngModel)]="_module.ClosingDate" ngControl="ClosingDate" #ClosingDate="ngForm">
<button type="submit" class="custombutton" (click)="Test1(ClosingDate, myInput.getAttribute('placeholder'))">Get Placeholder value</button>
```

```
Test1(closingDate, placeholder) {
  console.log(closingDate, placeholder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i'm not writing any formal argument in method, because i send more control names as a argument on button click, so not possible for me to send every controls placeholder value, and some controls don't have any placeholder value. Please suggest me another option.